# How to passing params whit file upload and get it in node js Ionic 3

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework

Server Node JS file upload whit multer :

```
 var multer      = require('multer');
        var storage = multer.diskStorage({
            destination: function (req, file, callBack) {
              console.log(req.body);
                callBack(null, 'public/images/');
            }, filename: function (req, file, callBack) {
              callBack(null, 'someName');
          }
        });

        var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('file');


          outer.post('/uploads',uploads.single('file'),
    function(req, res) {

      //console.log(JSON.stringify(req.files.file));
      console.log('/////////////////////////////////');
      console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
      console.log(JSON.stringify(req.params))
      console.log(req.files.file)
      var base64Data = req.files.file.data.toString('base64').replace(/^data:image\/jpeg;base64,/, "");
   //console.log(base64Data);
       var time = Date.now().toString()+"out.jpeg" ;

fs.writeFile('public/images'+"/"+time, base64Data, 'base64', function(err) {
console.log(err +' §§§§§§§§§§§'  ); 
}); 
      res.status(204).end();
    }
  );
```

Frontend Ionic 3 :

```
 var name = "upload";  


    var par = {
      token : this.myToken ,
      contenu_titre : this.contenu_titre ,
      contenu_text : this.contenu_text ,
      contenu_type : 'img' ,

    }  ;

    let option: FileUploadOptions = {
      params : par,
      fileKey:'file',
      mimeType:'image/jpeg',
      httpMethod:'POST',
      fileName:'user_step4#'+name
    };






    let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: "Uploading...."
    });
    loader.present();

    const fileTransfer:FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();

   // console.log('filename'+this.curfilename);

    fileTransfer.upload(this.photo  ,encodeURI(this.linkPic+"/publication/uploads"),option).then((result)=>
    {
      alert('uploaded')
      console.log('success');
      console.log(result);
      loader.dismiss();  
    }).catch(error=>{
   loader.dismiss();  
   alert(error);   
    console.log('uploaderror');
    console.log(error.message);  
    });   
    }
```

I want to get the Params values in the server ,
every time is undefined or null
i want to get some params whit my file to save the params in my database.
the upload is working fine but in not getting the params 
req.body return {}
and the req.file return onlu the filename and the file

Comment: I don't see req.params written anywhere in the server code. Can you try it please by console.log(req.params)?

Comment: the req.params return this {}

Comment: Can you place it in the code and update it here! It will give a clear picture.

Comment: it`s updated ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use **params with FileTransferOptions** to send parameters along with your file. 
**Use mimeType: "multipart/form-data"** to specify that this request contains multiple type of data

```
var options =
      {
        fileKey: "file",
        fileName: filename,
        chunkedMode: false,
        mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
        params: {

      "full_name": this.userForm.value.u_name,
      "email": this.userForm.value.u_email,
      "country": this.userForm.value.u_country,
      "state": this.userForm.value.u_state,
      "city": this.userForm.value.u_city,
      "pincode": this.userForm.value.u_pincode,
      "fax": this.userForm.value.u_fax,
      "address": this.userForm.value.u_address,

    }
  };


  transfer.upload(this.photo, this.yourURL, options).then(data =>
  {
           //Handle the response from the server
   }
```

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));  === {}
      console.log(JSON.stringify(req.params)) === {}
      console.log(req.files.file) ==={ name: 'user_step4#upload',
  data:
   <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 48 00 48 00 00 ff e1 00 4c 45 78 69 66 00 00 4d 4d 00 2a 00 00 00 08 00 02 01 12 00 03 00 00 00 01 00 06 ... >,
  size: 7275315,
  encoding: '7bit',
  tempFilePath: '',
  truncated: false,
  mimetype: 'multipart/form-data',
  md5: '89de88065be7f756eabae70e',
  mv: [Function: mv] }

Comment: I didn't understand your comment. Did it work or not ?

Comment: im changing this to multipart form data and its not working

Comment: The same code worked for me.The problem might be on the server side.

Comment: what the code return your params ? you have an express app un server side ?

Comment: Yes. My code successfully sends the file and all the parameters.

Comment: Its written in PHP